# How to Create Custom Partial CLasses in VS 2012 EF Model

Tags: frameworks, namespaces, entity, customizing

Just started using VS 2012 and I generated an EF Model from the database.  All worked fine, although in my previous experience I had to put a using  in my code.

I tried to set up a .cs file with partial classes to provide custom business logic behaviors to the generated classes and Intellisense does not recognize ar prompt with the generated classes.

I did as others have stated and brought up the properties panel of the Edmx model and fount the namespace.  However, when I try to put it in a using statement, Intellisense does not recognize it.

Am I missing something here?  EF can get very confusing and frustrating if one goes more than an inch or so below its generated surface.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that EF5 generates a model such that you do not need to have a "using namespace;" or a "namespace xxx"{} in the code file.

Just a simple xxx.cs file and each partial class definition you want to make:
public partial class MyClass
{

}